# Grep / awk greater than date

Tags: awk, grep, cut

I'm sure this is an easy one for the Gurus. I'm working on my get things done and todo system.
At the moment I've simply got a markdown file which I edit in VI and set tags against my things to do.

It looks like this

```
# My project | @home
- Do this this | @home
```

I think sync this file across my devices and use tasker / grep on android to show me the todo based on where I am.

I've now got to the stage where I want to add things to do in the future so I was thinking of something like

```
- Do this thing in the future | @home @2014-02-01
```

How could I exclude that line until the date is 2014-02-01?
My current command for just extract @home todos is

```
grep -e "@home" myfile | cut -d '|' -f1
```

I'm convinced there's a way of doing this, but google / stackoverflow hasn't lead me the right direction yet!

Help appreciated,

Thanks

Alan

Comment: For what it's worth, Task Coach is a good one if you don't want to roll your own. http://taskcoach.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk:

```
DAT=$(date +%Y%m%d)    # get today's date, for example 20140117
awk 'NF>3{gsub(/-/,"",$NF);if ($NF>d) next}{print $1}' FS="[|@]" d=$DAT file

# My project
- Do this this
```

Comment: Updated, how about this?

Comment: You can have the date read in `awk` like this: `awk 'NF>3{gsub(/-/,"",$NF);if ($NF>d) next}{print $1}' FS="[|@]" d=$(date +%Y%m%d) file`

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you. I'll have a play around myself now you've pointed me in the right direction, as ideally I 'd like to throw @tags in any position, but that's not  a huge issue.

Comment: @Jotne, thanks, I knew it can be merged into one command, but for myself, i like my style, that I can easily adjust and not make the code too long.

Answer (score 3):

Using Perl

```
perl -MTime::Piece -ne '
  BEGIN {$now = localtime}
  print unless /@(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d)/ and $now < Time::Piece->strptime($1, "%Y-%m-%d")
' <<END
# My project | @home
- Do this this | @home
- Do this thing in the future | @home @2014-02-01
END
```

```
# My project | @home
- Do this this | @home
```

Also, GNU awk

```
gawk '
    BEGIN {now = systime()}
    match($0,/@([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])-([0-9][0-9])-([0-9][0-9])/, m) {
        time = mktime(m[1] " " m[2] " " m[3] " 0 0 0")
        if (time > now) next
    }
    1
'
```

Comment: Thank youThanks Glenn! Both of these worked, unfortunately perl/gawk isn't available on android without me installing them

Answer (score 2):

For files that use dates in a format where the chronological order is the same as the lexical order, like `nginx error log` you can find the lines after a certain date using awk:

```
    awk -v "oneHourAgo=$(date +'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S' -d '1 hour ago')" '/^[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}/{ if ($0 >= oneHourAgo) print $0 }' /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

The error log might contain multiline errors that do not start with a date, so those are filtered out.