# Unix - Removing lines from file that have date in first column older than 7 days

Tags: date, unix, awk, unix-timestamp

I have the current log file being produced to monitor file space. However, I want to remove records in the file that are older than 7 days.

Example log file (filesize.log)

```
4/10/2016 0:03:48 Filesystem 6.0G 2.6G 3.1G 47% /
4/11/2016 0:08:59 Filesystem 6.0G 2.6G 3.1G 47% /
4/13/2016 0:06:41 Filesystem 6.0G 2.6G 3.1G 47% /
4/15/2016 0:00:16 Filesystem 6.0G 2.6G 3.1G 47% /
4/16/2016 0:03:46 Filesystem 6.0G 2.6G 3.1G 47% /
4/17/2016 0:07:53 Filesystem 6.0G 2.6G 3.1G 47% /
4/19/2016 0:02:26 Filesystem 6.0G 2.6G 3.1G 47% /
```

There is a lot of help out there for deleting files that are older than x date, but none that satisfy the removal of rows within a file based on the same.

I did find a couple of ideas like:
If you calculate the date up to which the lines shall be ignored before you call 
awk then you can do this:

```
awk -v cmpdate=20130628 '{line=$0; dateval=$8;FS="/"; $0=dateval; thisdate=$3*10000+$1*100+$2; if (thisdate>cmpdate) print line; FS=" ";}' file
```

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81829/delete-lines-in-a-csv-file-older-than-7-days

```
#!/bin/bash
head -n+2 filesize.log | {
  while read line ; do
    tmstmp=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $8}');
    echo "TMSTMP: $tmstmp" "TMDELTA: $(( $(date -d "now" +%s) - $(date -d "$tmstmp" +%s) ))" "TMWINDOW: $(( 604800 ))"
    [ $(( $(date -d "now" +%s) - $(date -d "$tmstmp" +%s) )) -lt $(( 604800 )) ] && echo "$line";
  done;
```

}

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81829/delete-lines-in-a-csv-file-older-than-7-days

```
awk 'NF>3{gsub(/-/,"",$NF);if ($NF>d) next}{print $1}' FS="[|@]" d=$(date +%Y%m%d) file
```

From [Grep / awk greater than date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174520/grep-awk-greater-than-date?newreg=7a54938abac54f9b8ca7c603ef19481d)

But, yet again, these aren't following the same date formatting I have been using, and I have been getting errors when trying to run these mentioned scripts.

Comment: Alternative approach: what about having your logfiles rotated everyday at midnight ?  One file per 24h period would probably be much easier to manage anyway.

Comment: Yeah, long log files are a solved problem; I think should look at [logrotate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate).  Your system might already have logrotate running and you just have to edit its configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, use C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

class line {
    std::string data;
public:
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, line const &l) { return os << l.data; }

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, line &l) { return std::getline(is, l.data); }

    bool operator<(time_t target) const {
        std::istringstream buffer(data);
        struct tm t;
        buffer >> std::get_time(&t, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S");
        return mktime(&t) < target;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    std::time_t now = std::time(NULL);
    struct tm tm = *std::localtime(&now);

    // For the moment I've hard-coded the number of days ago for the cut-off.
    // Should probably be configurable.
    tm.tm_mday -= 7;

    std::time_t target = mktime(&tm);

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        std::ifstream in(argv[1]);
        std::ofstream out(std::string(argv[1]) + ".trimmed");

        std::remove_copy_if(std::istream_iterator<line>(in), std::istream_iterator<line>(),
            std::ostream_iterator<line>(std::cout, "\n"),
            [&](line const &l) { return l < target; });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make a threshold in your format:

```
start=`date -d '7 days ago' +'%-m/%-d/%y %-H:%M:%S'`
```

More likely, you want to include any times from the first day:

```
start=`date -d '7 days ago' +'%-m/%-d/%y 0:00:00'`
```

And `>` is slightly more efficient than `>=`, so:

```
start=`date -d '8 days ago' +'%-m/%-d/%y 23:59:59'`
```

(Assuming your log uses 24-hour time.)

Then use `awk` to save lines you want to a temp file.

```
awk -v start="$start" '$1$2>start' filesize.log > filesize.last7days.log
```

Check that it worked, then overwrite the old file:

```
mv -f filesize.last7days.log filesize.log
```